# set the global state multipling x and y received from state. redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

> I want to import these 3 states: x and y are random generated number by a funtion, that works so I get the generated numbers

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      x: state.x,
      y: state.y,
      correctAnswer: state.correctAnswer
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
    return {
      generateX, 
      generateY,
      generatedAnswer
    }
  }
```

> Then I want to generate an answer that would be multipling X and Y and set that value to correctAnswer state value, this function is deployed when I click a button later

```
  generateAnswer = () => {
     this.props.correctAnswer: this.props.x*this.props.y
  }
```

> of course this is not working, has anyone any idea if this can work or what piece of code I am missing, I m sure this can be done but checked a lot of videos and have no idea what I am missing. I am new to react and redux and any help would be great...thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

you should not use this before props in a function.